# What programming language is Zillow written in?

Tags: java, zillow

Looking to find out what is the main programming language that drives the Zillow web based application. Does anyone know the answer to this?

Comment: It appears they switched from JBoss to Apache Coyote (still Java though)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Their homepage sends the following http header:

```
X-Powered-By: Servlet 2.4; JBoss-4.0.3SP1 (build: CVSTag=JBoss_4_0_3_SP1 date=200510231054)/Tomcat-5.5
```

Which, indicates java.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ curl -v -X HEAD http://www.zillow.com

< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Tue, 30 Oct 2012 14:37:55 GMT
< Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
< X-Powered-By: Servlet 2.4; JBoss-4.0.3SP1 (build: CVSTag=JBoss_4_0_3_SP1 date=200510231054)/Tomcat-5.5
< X-Internal-Host: 013
```

So Java EE 1.4 on the back end and Javascript on the front end.